PCB trace width for high current motor driver
This post is a continuation of Trace width for PCB motor driver board, with a few follow-ups and questions.
Firstly, I'd like to mention again that the motors I want to use have a maximum current of 7 A for when they stall, but their operating current is around 0.35 A. I'm concerned that for my application the motors might stall at some point the driver board might overheat even if I'll be adding heatsinks. I've widened the VCC 12 V trace which provides current to the motors from 2 mm to 3.5 mm. Since the pins of the MOSFETs I will use are quite close to each other, I've routed the power trace into them with 2 mm traces. Does this have any negative effect or is it standard practice?. From there, the rest of the power traces between the MOSFETs and to the motor connectors are 2 mm to 3 mm. The distance between the MOSFETs is quite short and so in theory there shouldn't be much heat generated if the motors stall, right?
I've also added a significant number of vias to stitch the ground planes from both sides of the board, which I believe will help with current and heat dissipation.
So the first question is whether the power traces seem acceptable now considering that the nominal current draw is less than 1 A for these motors in the case that they don't stall.
My second question is about whether the signal traces to my motor drivers are alright. Unfortunately, I had to make them quite long, and I want to use PWM signals to control the motor speed. Will my signal be affected by the length and width of the traces (longest trace is about 78 mm and their width is 0.4 mm).
The third question relates to whether the signal integrity for the motor encoder lines will be affected by the length and width of the trace or other factors (longest line is ~117.3 mm with a width of 0.5 mm).





There's no supply bypass capacitor?

What about stall detection? If you don‘t do that, then you need 7A capable traces.

Again, have you considered 2 oz copper?

@Hearth, I have but it's very expensive with JLCPCB for some reason.

@StefanWyss I'll look into stall detection. I didn't even know that such measures could be implemented.

@hdaniu Bear in mind that thicker copper puts restrictions on trace width. Maybe you have traces that are too thin for JLC's standard process at 2 oz?

I think the diodes from gate driver output to gate have the wrong direction. Typically one wants to use them for enhanced current sink. And I have doubts about the optocoupler use, there is no GND resistor to speed them up.
